# Error when building Haxe project from Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, haxe

I'm getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/Sublime Text/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime_plugin.py", line 549, in run_
    return self.run(edit)
  File "HaxeComplete in /Users/graphic/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages/Haxe.sublime-package", line 338, in run
  File "HaxeComplete in /Users/graphic/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages/Haxe.sublime-package", line 925, in run_build
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

In the console when I try to build my project. Is this a permissions issue or something? I'm unable to find much about it online when I search. I've tried different build targets to no avail, and I got the same error in Sublime Text 2.

As an important side note, the `Build` option in the menu is greyed out, and when I try to run it via keyboard shortcut I get "No Build System".

Comment: Seems this was a problem with the haxe install. Running `sudo haxe self update` fixed the issue.

Comment: You should post your comment as an answer

Comment: ++. Please, post your answer and mark the question as answered, or it will pollute "unanswered questions" list for years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem appeared to boil down to a combination of two things:

1. I made sure to get the latest version of Haxe and Haxelib.
2. When I tried to trigger a build from Sublime Text 3, I had to make sure to have the project's build XML file open and active. Once it was the active file, I'd then choose a build target and start the build. After it had built successfully, I could change the active file and still complete a build, but sometimes it would appear to "forget" and I'd have to go back to the XML file, choose a build target, and trigger the build once again from the build XML file.